# Precedence of the C++ Comma Operator

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, comma-operator

Hi I am a little confused with the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    while(val <= 10)
        sum += val, ++val;     //source of problem

    cout<<"Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << endl;
    //
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently learning about operator precedence. Know that the comma operator has the lowest precedence among the C++ operators, I was hoping that the statement in the while loop evaluate in the following order:

```
++val; //so that val is incremented to 2 the first time the code in the while loop is evaluated
sum += val; //so that the incremented value of val is added to the sum variable
```

But the code evaluated in this order instead:

```
sum += val;
++val;
```

Why did the comma operator seem to have affected the order of evaluation?

Comment: [Because it works in this way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: Why not just use `sum += ++val;` and now there is no ambiguity and everyone knows what you mean?

Comment: Or better yet, `++val; sum += val;`.

Comment: the comma operators main usage is to obfuscate code. There are some strange corners where it comes in handy, but never you want a comma operator for its own sake

Comment: Don't forget that code isn't written for the compiler : it's written for humans. If two lines convey a clearer intent, don't try to one-line it.

Comment: Well, you are not learning operator precedence.  You are learning what kind of code to never write.  Good thing.

Comment: @Nicol, that's only better if some braces are also added, else it's *much* worse!  (BTW, I do recommend the braces, in case that's not clear)

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica, I am not yet a developer, am learning to code. I only want to understand concepts now, so that I would be able to make the good decisions you have suggested when I start writing code that others may later have to deal with. Thank you and all for your explanations

Comment: @BiagioFesta thank you for the reference it was great!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not about precedence; it's about order of evaluation. The comma operator, unlike most other C++ operators (pre-C++17), *strictly* enforces a specific order of evaluation. Comma expressions are always evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: @NathanOliver: "*Why is it about order of evaluation?*" Because the OP asked "Why did the comma operator seem to have affected the order of evaluation?" The OP seems to clearly understand how the comma separates the two expressions in terms of parsing; his question is why they happen in that order.

Comment: Then why this doesn't follow:
`printf("%d %d  %d", x, x++, x++)`
Initially `x=0`

Comment: @Raj Because that is not the comma operator. :)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Can you explain why does it evaluate to `2 1 0`?

Comment: @Raj Not really. That code has undefined (pre-C++17) or unspecified (since C++17) behaviour. Don't write code like that. Why do you think you want to write code like that?

Comment: I don't like such piece of code, but sadly my hiring manager thinks it's a nice question to evaluate candidates :(

Comment: @Raj No one can. It is undefined behavior (UB) because the order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Comment: @Raj whether behavior is undefined or unspecified in the standard, the compiler has to make correct code behave in *some* way. Your compiler seems to push parameters left to right, and therefore post increments X and pushes the old value (zero), post increments and pushes the old value (now one), pushes the current value (2), and finally pushes the pointer to the string. *But* a different compiler might choose to push parameters left to right, hence 0, 0, 1, and leave X being equal to 2.

Comment: @UriRaz Did you mean "compiled code" instead of "correct code"? Because that is certainly not "correct code"...

Comment: @UriRaz -- or some other compiler might push the same value three times, then add 2 to `x`. Or any of a whole bunch of other possibilities. The order that the arguments get pushed has nothing to do with the order in which the expressions that produce the arguments get evaluated.

Comment: @Max Langhof By corrrect code I mean code that would compile with no error messages, rather than code that would correctly execute.

Comment: @UriRaz Your categories of code are not really adequate. According to the C++ standard, `int x = *(int*)(nullptr);` is invalid code - it has undefined behavior - yet most compilers will happily compile it to a binary (they wouldn't have to). ODR violations make a program literally ill-formed, but no compiler diagnostic is required. Again, compilers _could_ refuse the program with an error, but they don't have to. So it doesn't make sense to sort programs into "correct" and "incorrect" based on "the compiler will compile it" - that's not a property of the program but of the compiler you use.